# window.location prevent iframe from redirecting parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I have tried a number of ways to redirect automatically things I load into an iframe on one of my pages, and they always seem to trigger the parent window to reload/redirect rather than having the iframe directed to its desired spot.

I know most people want the opposite where when they are done in the iframe they want to have the parent window reloaded or have directed somewhere else. But in this case I want my script to continue on to another page.

Is there a built in mechanism that won't allow an iframe to redirect within itself?

lets for the sake of it pretend the code is

```
if(someAction === true) {
   window.location = '/some/new/path/index_new.html?param=something';
}
```

I have also tried this with `window.top.location` and `window.parent.location` and I think a couple other random variants. Including appending `.href` to the end of each variant. With out fail it seems that the parent window of the iframe is always redirecting instead of the actual iframe itself as hoped.

the iframe is a simple iframe

`<iframe src="/original/path/index.html"></iframe>`

the script that would be looking to redirect the iframe is embedded in /original/path/index.html

Comment: another thing worth mentioning is that I can physically click a link in the embedded source of my `/original/path/index.html` and the link directs fine in the iframe. Its just when I try to have it automatically redirect is where I seem to run into some issue or another. Unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Please post your code or snippet of your code so we can see what it is your are working with. I used an Iframe for a site that opened three different pages from the parent page all within the same frame and used cookies to go back and forth with the data. However, please show some html divs and or js so we can see how you want it to work. Here is some of the code for my work. I use local storage

```
    function Redirect($page) {
      localStorage.setItem('page',$page);
            window.location="validateorder.htm";

           }

    function orderValidate($page) {
      localStorage.setItem('page',$page);
      $arr = $('iframe').contents().find('form').serializeArray();

      $.each($arr,function(i,v){
            createCookie(i,v);
      });


      window.location="ordersummary.htm";
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').load(function() {
        $page = localStorage.getItem('page');
        $subtotal = localStorage.getItem('subtotal');
        $tax = localStorage.getItem('tax');
        $total = localStorage.getItem('total');
        $table = $('iframe').contents().find('td#optionsPrice');

        $form = $('iframe').contents().find('#frmContact');
        $theform = $('iframe').contents().find('#theform');

        if($table.length > 0){
            $('iframe').contents().find('td#optionsPrice').text($subtotal);
            $('iframe').contents().find('td#tax').text($tax);
            $('iframe').contents().find('td#totalPrice').text($total);
        }

        if($form.length > 0){
            $form.find('input').each(function(){
                $name = $(this).attr('name');
                $type = $(this).attr('type');
                if($type != 'button'){
                    $(this).val(readCookie($name));
                }
            });
        }
```